# Call web form method from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, static

Here is the scenario: I have a WCF service that sends a message to web interface.

I receive it in WCF interface implementation class. I want to display the message on another web form.

I tried to create a static method in web form and called it from WCF Service method. But the problem is that static methods can't access controls on the web form. I am really confused. Please give some ideas. Here is some code for your reference:

### WCF Method

```
public void ReceiveDownloadFileStatus(Int32 bytesDownloaded)
{    
   UploadForm.SetDownloadProgress(bytesDownloaded);
}
```

### Static Method in UploadForm.aspx

```
public static void SetDownloadProgress(Int32 bytesDownloaded)
{
    //access progress bar on form and update it from here

}
```

Comment: why there are WCF method on your web form? it should be separated from implementation on your web form.

Comment: It's not in web form. It's a separate class. That's the whole problem. How do I send message from WCF class to web form?

Comment: It's depend on your Service implementation, please share with us snippet your service code.

Comment: Wait, it just on separated class? Not project? You need to separate that on another project.

Comment: The first method is service implementation.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing a static reference to your latest instance and using the controls of that? Not exactly the way it should be done (you should pass around the references either at creation or in a static context), but better than nothing if you want a quick solution.

Comment: Can you please give example of how to pass around reference?

Comment: I'd stick with the easiest method - just make a static variable, assign it to your own service instance at instantination and use that instance to call your method.